# Is it possible to display some text data in list format without using list-view in android?

Tags: android

**scenario :** I have two pages,first page contains one edit-text box and a button.After clicking of that button,the value from that edit-text will be just shown on the second page.After clicking of back from the second screen,it will navigate to the first page and the same process begins.
Here  the requirement is i need to show that data in list format without using list-view in android.Is it possible?if so how?

suggestions please..

Thanks for your precious time!...

Comment: you can add them in a textview..

Comment: what's wrong with a list view ? put an ArrayAdapter<String> to it, arrayadapter.add(String), and that's all you need to do.

Comment: ya you can add dynamic  view on vertical linear layout

Comment: @Sushil i have only one text-view okay.but i need to print like a list format

Comment: Google -> addView, findViewById, new constructor, setText

Comment: Without the background to *why* you can't use a ListView, I'm not sure how useful the answers will be.  Suggestions like "put the list in a single Textview" or "put multiple TextViews in a LinearLayout" are fine, but they're just guessing at ways to work around what seems like an arbitrary rule.

Comment: You can append in text view. tv.append()

Comment: You can use `ListView` with a great ease and make very good looking and attractive UI.
By the way why are you adamant on reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation

```
<LinearLayout
   id="@+id/myownlist"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Get it in code

```
LinearLayout myVeryOwnList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myownlist);
```

Add your text views in your very own list.

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < TOTAL_ITEMS_YOU_HAVE ; j ++) {
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   myVeryOwnList.addView(tv);
}
```